# type.js with html entities

Tags: javascript, html, type.js

I am trying to use type.js to animation a code example but th problem is it types the characters of the html entity first then coverts to the corresponding html character.

Example:

I want to type `<!DOCTYPE html>` so I have use `&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;` but as I said it types < and then flash's to <

Is there a way not to show the `&l` as it is typing and just show the <

```
$(function(){
    $(".element").typed({
        strings: ["&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; "],
        typeSpeed: 500,
        backSpeed: 500,
        loop: true
    });
});
```